# Pass string value as int from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Lets i have following view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
     public string SomeValue {get; set;}
     public int CountryId {get; set;}
}
```

And country list

```
var countryList = new[]{new[]{Country="Russia", Value=1},new[]{Country="USA", Value=2},new[]{Country="Germany", Value=3} }
```

I want to create a form with these fields. The problem is that country input must be TEXTBOX.

So i cannt just write something like `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CountryId)`. What is best practices for such tasks? Is it hidden field or maybe something else?

---

EDIT

Interface looks like :

```
    SomeValue: |_______|

    Country:   |_______|

                |Submit button|
```

In field Country we can type only country name. In SomeValue some other value it doesnt matter what(you can imagine that SomeValue doesnt exists).

Comment: Let be be clear, you want to type `Germany` in a textbox, submit the form, and want to get 3 in controller action? Don't you think `DropdownList` whould be a better option? Or textbox is the requirement?

Comment: @Mohayemin Yes, textbox is the requirement.

Comment: why not just use a drop down list like every other site on the net? Then problem is then solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly a strange requirement when a dropdown list seems far more appropriate, but we've all had strange requirements before. :)  Here's a simple example which will hopefully demonstrate everything you need to know in order to get this working.

Firstly, a simple model to relate a country name with an id:

```
public class CountryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Now the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string country)
    {
        var countryId = GetCountries()
                        .Where(c => c.Country.ToLower() == country.ToLower())
                        .Select(c => c.Id)
                        .SingleOrDefault();

        if (countryId != 0)
            return RedirectToAction("Thanks");
        else
            ModelState.AddModelError("CountryNotSelected", "You have selected an invalid country.");

        return View();
    }

    private List<CountryModel> GetCountries()
    {
        return new List<CountryModel>
        {
            new CountryModel { Id = 1, Country = "Russia" },
            new CountryModel { Id = 2, Country = "USA" },
            new CountryModel { Id = 3, Country = "Germany" }
        };
    }
}
```

Here's the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("Country")
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

There are a couple of things to note here.  Firstly, you've already stated that you have extra properties in this view.  In that case, I'd put them in a `CountryViewModel` and model bind to an instance of that in the HTTP POST method, rather than simply binding to a string.  So, something like this:

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public string SomeMoreFormData { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Then from here, the POST method would change to something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CountryViewModel viewModel)
{
    var countryId = GetCountries()
                    .Where(c => c.Country.ToLower() == viewModel.Country.ToLower())
                    .Select(c => c.Id)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

    if (countryId != 0)
        return RedirectToAction("Thanks");
    else
        ModelState.AddModelError("CountryNotSelected", "You have selected an invalid country.");

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Secondly, notice how I'm creating the country list via `GetCountries()`. This would allow you to easily refactor this later to grab a country list from a database if your requirements change.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")) {    
<p>
Page number:
@Html.TextBox("CountryId")

<input type="submit" value="CountryId" />
</p>
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int countryId)
{ 
CountryId= countryId;
}
```

Comment: Well...in your code user just see id of country(1,2,3,4,5) but i need solution where user can write to text USA click submit and we get Id of country in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question 100%.  Am I correct in saying that the user can type in the country id and name?

It is better to send a view model to your view.  Lets say that you have the following view model:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public string CountryName {get; set;}
     public string CountryId {get; set;}
}
```

Your action method could look like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     YourViewModel viewModel = new YourViewModel();

     return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourViewModel viewModel)
{
     // Check viewModel for nulls
     // Whatever was typed in on the view you have here,
     // so now you can use it as you like
     string country = viewModel.CountryName;
     string id = viewModel.CountryId;

     // Do whatever else needs to be done
}
```

Your view could look like this:

```
@model YourProject.DomainModel.ViewModels.YourViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     <div>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CountryName)<br />
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CountryName)
     </div>

     <div>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CountryId)<br />
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CountryId)
     </div>

     <button id="SaveButton" type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, user can type only country name.

Comment: How does the country then get generated?  If this is the case then why don't you just modify my code and take out the country id?

Comment: How to generate countryId is main point of my question. If we just take out the country id field from view then how we can get it in viewmodel?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  I would add the country to the database and get it to return the next available id.